# Convertir una cifra double en String

Tags: java

estoy intentando convertir una cifra (Double) introducida por teclado en String,

ejemplo => 8.3 => ocho con tres

He creado una clase scanner para introducir el double y tenía entendido que con valueOf podía hacerlo, pero debo estar haciendo algo mal lógicamente...

```
    public static void main(Double[] args) {

    String cadena;

    System.out.println ("Introduzca nota: ");
    //Creación de un objeto Scanner
    Scanner oNota = new Scanner (System.in);
    Double nota = oNota.nextDouble ();

    cadena = String.valueOf(nota);
    System.out.print(cadena);
    }
```

Además estoy un poco bloqueado con la cabecera de la clase principal, se supone que no debe ser void porque quiero que devuelva un valor, pero si la quito me da error. ¿El Double de la cabecera está bien? Entiendo que si se introduce un double... eso debe ser Double. ¿Es así?

Gracias.

Comment: usa double no Double , edité mi respuesta.

Comment: *pero debo estar haciendo algo mal lógicamente...*... No has explicado lo que está funcionando mal.

Comment: @rodic Creo que no esta especificada tu pregunta, dime, si introduces 8.3 que valor deseas obtener?

Comment: Te actualice mi respuesta, si no te sirve explica un poco más lo que quieres conseguir hacer.

Comment: Hola, siento haber tardado tanto, si introduzco 8.3 deseo obtener "ocho con tres". Lo he visto hacer de otra forma, pero me parecía mas complejo y largo y me comentaron que con valueOf se podía hacer.

Comment: con `valueOf` no se puede hacer eso. Alguien te dio información incorrecta :)

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que ya lo estas realizando correctamente, recibes un valor tipo `double` almacenado en la variable `nota`, usa double no Double (tipo primitivo):

```
double nota = oNota.nextDouble();
```

y lo conviertes a String, mediante `String.valueOf()` :

```
 cadena = String.valueOf(nota);
```

para imprimirlo incluso puedes no necesitar convertirlo a String:

```
 System.out.print(nota);
```

Answer (score 0):

El valueOf esta bien, prueba a introducir el double con la ",", por ejemplo 8,5 en vez de el "." ya que tu Locale es España. Si lo quieres con el punto indicale el Locale de otro país donde se use el punto y no te dara error :

```
Scanner oNota = new Scanner (System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

EDIT: Ahora que me fijo el main no puede ir con Double

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
```

Si lo que quieres es comprobar que son doubles para hacer algo con ellos:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        Double[] dbs=new Double[args.length];
        String doublePatron = "([0-9]*)\\.([0-9]*)";  

        for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
        {
            if(Pattern.matches(doublePatron, args[i]))
                 dbs[i]=Double.valueOf(args[i]);
            else
                dbs[i]=-1.0;
            System.out.println(dbs[i]);
        }

        }
```

En este caso si ejecutamos:

```
java -jar JavaApplication6.jar 7.5 5.5 A
```

Nos retornaría por consola:

```
7.5
5.5
-1.0
```

EDIT 2:

Con esto pasas de numero a texto del 0 al 9.9, si necesitas mas es sencillo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Double[] dbs=new Double[args.length];
    String doublePatron = "([0-9]*)\\.([0-9]*)";  

    for(int i=0;i<args.length;i++)
    {
        if(Pattern.matches(doublePatron, args[i]))
        {
            String numeroEscrito="";
            for(char c:args[i].toCharArray())
            {
            switch (c){
             case '0':
                 numeroEscrito+="cero";
                 break;
             case '1':
                 numeroEscrito+="uno";  
                 break;
              case '2':
                 numeroEscrito+="dos";
                 break;
             case '3':
                 numeroEscrito+="tres";  
                 break;                    
             case '4':
                 numeroEscrito+="cuatro";
                 break;
             case '5':
                 numeroEscrito+="cinco";  
                 break;
              case '6':
                 numeroEscrito+="seis";
                 break;
             case '7':
                 numeroEscrito+="siete";  
                 break;    
              case '8':
                 numeroEscrito+="ocho";
                 break;
             case '9':
                 numeroEscrito+="nueve";  
                 break;  
             case '.':
                 numeroEscrito+="con";

            }
            numeroEscrito+=" ";//faltaria quitarle el ultimo espacio        

            }
            System.out.println(numeroEscrito);
        }
        else
            System.out.println(args[i]+" no es un Double");
    }

    }
```

para:

```
java -jar JavaApplication6.jar 8.6 8.5 A
```

Da de salida:

```
ocho con seis
ocho con cinco
A no es un Double
```

Comment: Gracias, soy muy nuevo en esto... sabía que había algo raro en la cabecera del main, no me cuadraba, pero he probado de todo, en el caso que me dices, retorna el mismo número, (7.5 5.5 -1.0) pero yo necesito que salga en texto, es decir, (siete con cinco, cinco con cinco y menos uno con cero) aunque este último caso es más extraño.

Comment: Te metí otro edit, con eso ya te bastaría, meterle el menos es muy fácil añadirle su case y listo. Saludos,

Comment: Gracias ReyJuanjo, voy a probar con esto último que me has dicho, esa era la forma que veía yo en internet y foros, por eso me parecía extraño lo de valueOf. quizá no me expliqué bien cuando hable con la persona.

Comment: Suerte, si te sirvió valida la respuesta.

Comment: Hola ReyJuanjo, en mi caso el número necesito introducirlo por teclado, ¿necesitaría crear un scanner al inicio?

Comment: Si, y en vez de leer los datos de args, leerlos del Scanner.

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿que función hace exactamente Double[] dbs = new Double[args.length];? ¿es ahí donde debo cambiar args por la variable double que yo declare para introducirla por teclado?